# restoring the state of checkboxes from an array of 0 and 1s

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox, oracle-apex

I want to restore the state of my checkboxes in an ORACLE APEX tabular form.
The selection is made in the first column using the APEX row selector f01.

I saved the checkkboxes state in a collection and from there to an array
in a region item called P250_JSON,whereby the value of P250_JSON
 is a character string: '[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]' for example if the 1st and 4th
row are selected.

From this array [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]

I want to programatically click on the 1st and 4th row element of a tabular form
and restore the original choices when required.

Beginner in Jquery but I got this far:

```
var x = $v("P250_JSON");
var arrBoxes = jQuery.parseJSON(x);


$.each(arrBoxes,
      function(index,val){
      $("input[name='f01']").attr("checked","checked");
                           });
```

Obviously this checks all the checkboxes,so there is something missing.

The HTML for  row 16 is: 
label for="f01_0015" class="hideMeButHearMe">Select Row/label input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="15" class="row-selector" id="f01_0015"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: because `$("input[name='f01']")` selects all the checkboxes... It does not magically know the one you want, you need to tell it which one.

Comment: Exactly. This is what the question is about. One needs to loop through the array and the  row together and check the row where the array has a '1'. How to do this using Jquery?

Comment: `.eq()` http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure if it will work for you without also seeing the HTML, but try this:

```
$.each(arrBoxes,
      function(index,val){
      if(val) {
          $("input[name='f01']").get(index).attr("checked","checked");
      }
                           });
```

You need to only select the checkbox of the same index of the current item in `arrBoxes`, and only check it if the current value is not falsey.

Comment: Good catch. It's unrelated to OP's question, though, so I'm not sure if I should make that change. It would also be possible to avoid having to make two jQuery calls by using `.checked = true`.

Comment: Are you sure all your checkboxes are named `f01`? This seems to work fine for me ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vzrnjdb5/)).

Comment: tr><td  headers="CHECK$01"><label for="f01_0000" class="hideMeButHearMe">

Comment: @Leckraj That doesn't tell me much. Assuming that's a label for one of your checkboxes, is the checkbox ID the same as the name? If so, change the jQuery selector to `$("input[name^='f01']")`; this will match all inputs whose names *begin* with `f01`.

Comment: tr><td  headers="CHECK$01"><label for="f01_0001" class="hideMeButHearMe"> sorry posted too soon...f01_0000 to f01_0020 for the 20 rows so f01 is ok..

Comment: <tr><td  headers="CHECK$01"><label for="f01_0015" class="hideMeButHearMe">Select Row</label><input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="15" class="row-selector" id="f01_0015" is for row16.. But still no good,maybe something wrong in my setup.value = row number -1,thought it was 0 or 1! maybe that's why..

Comment: Could you edit your original question to contain the full relevant HTML?

Comment: This answer is BAD on many levels. Looking up things on every iteration. BAD. Wrapping it with another jQuery selector because of DOM look-up. BAD. Using attr - BAD.

Comment: @epascarello This isn't codereview. The double selector is a fair cop because I admittedly forgot about `.eq`, but I'm not going to fix OP's other issues. It's also worth pointing out that `$.each` is unnecessary because a simple `for` loop would be clearer and faster.

Comment: Yes it is not code review, but your lack of knowledge of `eq()` just produced a bad answer. Yeah the code works,  so does opening a window with a hammer. Yeah it was quick way to open a window, but it will lead to issues in the future.

Comment: I can definitely accept that the lack of `.eq` makes it a bad answer, but I feel that the remainder of the code shouldn't be modified because it's irrelevant to the question. Either way, it's up to OP to choose a correct answer; if he leaves mine marked, I'll edit away the double selector for the benefit of anybody reading this in the future.

Comment: On the use of attr or prop, you should review this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/368467

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that all the checkboxes you want to check are named as `<input name="f01" />`. If they are not, than you need to show some mark-up in your question.

```js
var arrBoxes = [1,0,0,1,0];

var checkboxes = $("input[name='f01']"); //get all the checkboxes
$.each(arrBoxes, //loop through your array
  function(index, val) {
    checkboxes.eq(index) //get the current checkbox
      .prop("checked", val === 1); //set checked state based on index value
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="f01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="f01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="f01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="f01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="f01" />
```

Comment: Both answers were correct. I forgot to parse using the first answer thats why it did not work.Thanks to everyone, I am really grateful.

Comment: I see you unselected my answer and picked the other. If you did what is in the other answer, you are looking at bad performance.